# Two classes from one package FXMLLoader error

Tags: javafx

When I attempt to load an FXML file that is in the same package as the controller that is calling for the loading I get a ClassNotFound exception referring to the controller class of the FXML file that is being loaded.  When I attempt to load an FXML file with the same name from a different package than the package containing the calling controller the file loads as expected.

Here is the code from the projectselectorcontroller class.  The commented code is the line that causes the exception.

```
@Override
public void Response(KWMessage Message)
{
    if(Message.getType() != -1)
    {
        switch(Message.getType())
        {
            case 6000:
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        //This file loads as expected   
                        ExtendedNode node = mainController.load("/newproject/newproject.fxml");


                        //This file does not load   
                        //ExtendedNode node = mainController.load("/projectselector/newproject.fxml");


                        NewProjectController controller = (NewProjectController)node.getController();
                        mainController.setCurrentNode(node);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the load method.  I have checked the URL and found that it is correct.  Is it possible that two controller classes cannot reside in the same package?

```
public ExtendedNode load(String FXML)
{
        ExtendedNode node;

    URL location = getClass().getResource(FXML);
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(location);
    fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
    try
    {
        node = new ExtendedNode();
        node.setNode((Parent)fxmlLoader.load(location.openStream()));
        node.setController((iMainController)fxmlLoader.getController());
        node.getController().setMainController(this);
    }
    catch (IOException ex){node = null;}
    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to load FXML files located in the same package as the controller class file without difficulty.  I am similarly able to load FXML files located in another package available relative to the one in which the controller class resides.

A common reason for a ClassNotFound Exception while loading FXML markup is not properly naming the controller class in the root level node of your markup file.  You need a fully qualified Java object name in the fx:controller attribute, eg:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="ServicesEditor" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" 
    minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
    styleClass="stage-pane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
    fx:controller="org.kkk.mm.censusassistant.GUIServicesEditorController">
```

I would first examine your markup files at both locations to assure that both had a fully qualified Java name for your controller class and that both identified the correct class.

If the controller class is properly identified in your project namespace and you are still getting a ClassNotFound exception, then I'll need more context in order to help you.  Are you certain that it is the fxmlloader.load() method call that is generating this error?  If not...

The logic you show for loading your markup seems convoluted.  I'm not sure what the ExtendedNode objects are doing or why you're using them.

You're using:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
fxmlLoader.setLocation(location);
:
:
node.setNode((Parent)fxmlLoader.load(location.openStream()));
```

Because you've already set the URL for the FXMLLoader with setLocation, you do not then need to call fxmlLoader with an inputStream.  You can just simply use fxmlLoader.load();

Comment: Thanks scottb.  You are correct it was an issue with a fully qualified name.  The ExtendedNode is just a convenience class to hold both the node and the controller together.